# Sense 120Vac With 5V Arduino Using Optoisolator Transistor TLP290-4

Tags: arduino, transistors

I am new to this, so I apologize in advance. I am trying to determine if I am calculating this correctly for a circuit to sense if 120Vac is present with a 5V Arduino Uno. My plan is to use the TLP290-4 optoisolator.

Based on the data sheet the LED forward current is 50mA and the Current transfer ratio (going with the min) is 50%. First I figured in order to keep the power dissipation somewhere around 2 watts I would use 10kohm resistor in series with L(hot) which should give a total of around 1.5watts (1.44ish) with 12mA or would it be 2.89watts with 17mA using 120*1.414?. On the output side I would use a 1/6watt 10kohm pullup resistor and 1µF capacitor, connected from VCC to the pin with the pullup resistor lets say its DI4 on the Arduino. Is anything im missing?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: please draw a schematic diagram of the circuit using the provided tool ... click the button that looks like a schematic diagram to activate the tool ... click `save and insert` after you complete the diagram

Comment: Do you just want to check the presence or do you need phase information like zero crossings?

Comment: Why a four channel chip? So far it sounds like you only need one channel.

Comment: 50 mA is an absolute maximum! Your design should use much less.